# How to center align a form with labels inside div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to center align a form with labels inside div.login__box

I use bootstrap 3.3.7

That's how I want it

[image: link]

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="login">логин</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="login" class="form-control" id="login" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd" >пароль</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="btn" />
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="button" class="form-control login__btn-login" id="btn" value="войти в личный кабинет">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

My current markup is here
[codepen.io](http://codepen.io/ckpunmep/pen/vXmzjw)

Comment: Codepen and the html in question does not match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight changes made to your html:

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>#</title>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
        </head>

        <body>
          <div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4 about__box">
                    <div class="about__inner">
                      <div class="about__content">
                        <div class="about__header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>

                        <div class="about__desc">sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-8 login__box">
                    <div class="login__inner">
                      <div class="text-center login__header">
  Authorization
                      </div>
                      <div class="container login__container">
                        <form class="form-horizontal">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2" for="login">log in</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <input type="login" class="form-control" id="login" required>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="control-label col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2" for="pwd" >password</label>
                              <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" required>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2  col-sm-offset-2" for="btn" ></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                  <input type="button" class="form-control login__btn-login" id="btn" value="submit">
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </form>
                              <div class="control-label col-sm-2"></div>
                              <div class="col-sm-8 login__desc">
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                              </div>
                            <img src="" class="pull-right img-responsive login__img_people">
                            </div>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
              </body>
```

Add this to your css:

```
.form-horizontal .control-label{
  margin-right:0;
}
```

Attaching codepen linksas well:

http://codepen.io/Sky-123/pen/WGOOqq?editors=1100

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

add an `margin-right:auto` and `margin-left:auto` to `.login__inner` and you must set the width :

```
.login__inner{
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add class col-lg-3-offset to the form

```
<form class="form-horizontal col-lg-3-offset col-lg-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="login">логин</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="login" class="form-control" id="login" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd" >пароль</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="btn" />
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="button" class="form-control login__btn-login" id="btn" value="войти в личный кабинет">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```